# How to reformat a HighChart series to for CSV export

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

We're using HighCharts 4.2.2 and the [export-csv](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/7/Export%20Data) plugin.

This is what our CSV export looks like:

[image]

Now the are 3 columns for **AAPL** but we only care about the `y` column. The following code was our attempt at removing the other 2 keys (`x` and `end`) from the priceLine series options object.

```
const updatePriceLine = (chart) => {
    const priceLine = chart.get('series-priceline');
    const prices = priceLine.data.map(point => point.y);
    console.log('prices', prices)
    priceLine.update({ keys: ['price'] });
    priceLine.data = prices;
    console.log('priceLine.data', chart.get('series-priceline').data)
    return chart;
};
```

---

The above worked to remove the `x` and `end` columns however there is nothing in the `y` column.

I thought it was that our new data array needed to be an array of objects with a `y` key, so tried this updated function, but did not work either:

```
const updatePriceLine = (chart) => {
    const priceLine = chart.get('series-priceline');

    const prices = priceLine.data.map((point) => {
        return {
            y: point.y
        };
    });

    priceLine.update({ keys: ['y'] });
    priceLine.data  = prices;
    console.log('priceLine.data', chart.get('series-priceline').data)
    return chart;
};
```

priceLine.data

[image]

priceLine.keys

[image]

^ original keys

---

**After removing the extra keys/columns:**

[image]

And the CSV now has the AAPL (x) and AAPL (end) columns removed, however there is no data in the AAPL column :(

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Finally figured it out!

Had to remove the line where I set the series to a `const`

```
const updatePriceLine = (chart) => {
    // const priceLine = chart.get('series-priceline');
    const prices = chart.get('series-priceline').data.map((point) => {
        return {
            x: point.x,
            y: point.y
        };
    });

    chart.get('series-priceline').update({ keys: ['y'] });
    chart.get('series-priceline').setData(prices)
    return chart;
};
```

So just called the `.update` and `.setData` directly on the `chart.get('series-priceline')`